# Are conditional expressions broken within packages?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, delphi-xe, conditional-compilation, conditional-expressions

Consider the following snippet:

```
requires
  designide,
  rtl,
  vcl,
  {$IF RTLVersion < 19.0}            // E2026 Constant expression expected
  //{$IF CompilerVersion = 22.0}     // same as above
  vcljpg;
  {$ELSE}
  vclimg;
  {$IFEND}
```

It seems to be absolutely syntactically correct. However, the compiler chokes on it and reports `Constant expression expected`. What really happens here?

Technical: currently tested on XE (15.0.3953.35171) only.

Of course, workaround suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: FWIW: In D2007 the `{$IF RTLVersion < 19.0}` test works if used **after** the `contains`clause.

Comment: @Ulrich Gerhardt, quite interesting observation, thanks! (confirmed with XE)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the same issue in the past even with delphi 2007. As workaround, I use a inc file with the conditional defines and then use `{$IFDEF}` instead of `{$IF}`

something like so

```
{$I MyDefines.INC}


requires
  designide,
  rtl,
  vcl,
 {$IFDEF DELPHI_XE_UP} //the DELPHI_XE_UP is defineed inside of MyDefines.INC
  uNewlib;
 {$ELSE}
  uOldLib;
 {$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Which `defines.inc` you'd recommend to reuse  (amongst maintained and w/o viral license)?

Comment: Try using the inc files included in the jedi project (jcl or jvcl)

Answer (score 8):

`package` modules are different from `program` and `library` modules. They do not contain executable code and you cannot `use` units. Therefore, symbols like `RTLVersion` are simply not visible from a package file. Your only option is to use `$IFDEF`.

Comment: And it is not exactly correct, see Ulrich Gerhardt's comment to OP.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that but it's fairly useless sadly since the only thing that comes after `contains` is `end.`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm convinced what i just found the cause. Consider the following:

```
{$IF not Declared(RTLVersion)}
{$MESSAGE WARN 'There is no RTL'}
{$IFEND}
{$IF not Declared(CompilerVersion)}
{$MESSAGE WARN 'nor are compiler intrinsics at all'}
{$IFEND}
{$IF not Declared(System)}
{$MESSAGE ERROR 'Because package not uses System implicitly'}
{$IFEND}
```

So, it appears to be what compiler behaves correctly, but issues a rather misleading (if not erroneous) message about symbol not being a constant expression, while symbol in question actually is **undeclared**!