# There is "unit aliases" option, but is there "package aliases" too?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction

Basically, i'm seeking perfectionist solution for the [conditional compilation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305657/are-conditional-expressions-are-broken-within-packages) and the goal is to make compiler to not complain about missing obsoleted package but use newer superseding package automagically (as it behaves with unit aliases).

I realize that it might be not best option thow, as unit aliases appears to hide possible namespace conflicts. However, if it present somewhere (i cant find it myself) - i'd like to try it out.

Comment: Hi there, you don't need to post the same question twice. People here always tries to answer as best as they can but give them some time ;)

Comment: @TLama, this one is dedicated to one of (specific) possible solutions, while previous one is more general and focuses on the cause (which, i believe, i found within passed 1 hour between those questions)

Comment: use conditional comp or different .dpk for different delphi version. Latter seems quite common.

Comment: @David Heffernan, please follow the link, conditional compilation is much less powerful when used in package source and varying package source itself is even worse.

Comment: I know all that. What's your alternative that's better? Why do you think everyone does it the way I said?

Comment: The problem with different packages for different versions is the actual solution imo but it makes managing them so much more complicated. If you add new units, or change something you have to do it for every version all the time.

Comment: @stefan true, but what's the alternative. Myself, I'd just script it with Perl or some such.